Does half of the sequence $\left(n^{\alpha}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ have even integer part/floor?
Define $e\left((a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty};N\right)$ to be the amount of members of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that are $\leq N$ and have even integer part (also known as the floor of the number).
My question/conjecture is:

Considering the sequence $\left(n^{\alpha}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},$ for
which values of $\alpha>1$ does $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty}
 \frac{e(n^\alpha;N)}{N^{1/\alpha}} = \frac{1}{2} ?$

This is trivially true for integer $\alpha,$ so it is non-integer values of $\alpha$ I am interested in.
I suspect that either this is true for all $\alpha,$ or maybe something like: $\limsup=1$ and $\liminf=0$ is true for all $\alpha$ instead. I'm not sure how to investigate it though.
Maybe this is in the book "Uniform distribution of sequences" by L. Kuipers and H Neiderreiter but I am not well-read on this book and was hoping for a relatively elementary proof or disproof of my conjecture.
